# Looping each() loop infinitely

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to loop through each li element under a ul displaying them one by one. Here is the code:

```
  $('.article_ticker li:first').siblings().hide();
  var list=$('.article_ticker li:first').siblings();

  list.each(function(index)
  {
      $(this).siblings().hide().delay(2000).fadeOut();
      $(this).fadeIn('fast');
  });
```

This code works fine but once the 'each' loop ends, it doesn't repeat the sequence. I want to cycle to be repeated infinitely. Like after the last element fades out, first element should fade in.

Comment: How are you expecting elements to `fadeOut()` ***after*** they've already been hidden via `hide()`?

Comment: I think you should consider a timer or a trigger

Comment: I can't imagine how this is a good idea either in terms of UX or, particularly code performance. You're essentially talking about an endless loop, which is a recipe for trouble. Incidentally, your two code lines can be merged as  `$(this).siblings().hide().delay(2000).end().fadeIn('fast');`

Comment: well i understand that its not a good idea or may not be even feasible with this approach...but what can be the solution?

Comment: Ok, I am using following piece of code to accomplish this:

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('.article_ticker li:first').siblings().hide();

    loop();
    
    function loop()
    {
          $('.article_ticker li:first').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000,function(){
       $(this).next().fadeIn('1000');
       $(this).appendTo('.article_ticker');
    loop();
      
      });
    }

});
   </script>

My doubt is about the 'appendTo' method. Does this method removes the element from top and insert it at the bottom? Does it actually REMOVES?

Comment: @MrinalPurohit: Did you manage to get it working? Can you approve one of the answers below?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(e) { $('.article_ticker li:first').siblings().hide(); loop(); function loop() { $('.article_ticker li:first').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000,function(){ $(this).next().fadeIn('1000'); $(this).appendTo('.article_ticker'); loop(); }); } }); </script> THIS CODE WORKS FOR ME PERFECTLY...I found it from one of my friends.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following...

```
$('.article_ticker li:first').siblings().hide();
var list=$('.article_ticker li:first').siblings();

(function repeatTicker() {
  list.each(function(index) {
    $(this).siblings().hide().delay(2000).fadeOut();
    $(this).fadeIn('fast');
  });
  setTimeout(repeatTicker, 10);
} ());
```

I'm using a setTimeout here otherwise the browser will complain that your page is not responding.
Now I used 10ms, but I would increase it as much as possible.

Comment: Ok, I am using following piece of code to accomplish this:

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('.article_ticker li:first').siblings().hide();

    loop();
    
    function loop()
    {
          $('.article_ticker li:first').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000,function(){
       $(this).next().fadeIn('1000');
       $(this).appendTo('.article_ticker');
    loop();
      
      });
    }

});
   </script>

My doubt is about the 'appendTo' method. Does this method removes the element from top and insert it at the bottom? Does it actually REMOVES?

Comment: If you move an existing node it will be removed from its previous position. It can not be in 2 places at the same time. I see you call loop from loop itself. This isn't going to work. First the browser will complain that your page hangs and you will blow up the call stack eventually. Use a setTimeout to solve these problems.